# How prove $\sqrt{r^2+c^2}$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question:**

> Let $a,b,c$ are integer numbers,and $r$ real numbers, and
>   $$ar^2+br+c=0,ac\neq 0$$
>
> show that
>
> $$\sqrt{r^2+c^2}$$ is irrational.

**My idea:** 
Note that,
$$\sqrt{r^2+c^2}=\sqrt{r^2+(ar^2+br)^2}=r\sqrt{1+(ar+b)^2}$$
Then how to proceed?
This is China South East Mathematical Olympiad problem yesterday

Comment: Note that it's equally general (but simpler to write) to take $c=1$ and allow $a,b$ to be rationals

Comment: Tagging this is elementary-number-theory until proven otherwise.

Comment: hint: let $y = \sqrt{r^2+c^2}$. You then get an equation in $y$.

Comment: Is $r$ a variable on the square root expression? Or, is it fixed for some value in $\mathbb{R}$? There are plenty of values for which it is an integer, and also proper rationals.

Comment: is this a problem from a book?  how do we know that it is true?

Comment: This is China South East Mathematical Olympiad problem yesterday

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $\sqrt{r^2+c^2}\in\mathbb{Q}$, and consider two cases:

*Case $b\ne0$.*

This implies that $br+c=-ar^2\in\mathbb{Q}$ and consequently $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that $r=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Since $ap^2+bpq+cq^2=0$ we conclude, as usual that $p|c$ and $q|a$. So let us define integers $a'$ and $b'$ by $$a=qa'\quad\hbox{and} \quad c=pc'.$$

Now $$ \sqrt{r^2+c^2}=\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{1+(c'q)^2}=\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{n}\tag{1} $$ where $n=1+(c'q)^2\in\mathbb{N}$. This implies that $\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, because we assumed that $\sqrt{r^2+c^2}\in\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $n$ is the square of an integer, which is absurd since $c'q<\sqrt{n}<c'q+1$. This contradiction proves the assertion, in this case.$\qquad\square$

*Case $b=0$.*

Here we have $r^2=-c/a>0$ so
$$\sqrt{r^2+c^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{4c^2a^2-4ca}=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{n}\tag{2} $$
where $n=4c^2a^2-4ca\in\mathbb{N}$. Again. this implies that $\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, because we assumed that $\sqrt{r^2+c^2}\in\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $n$ is the square of an integer, which is absurd since $(2ca)^2< n<(2ca-1)^2$. This contradiction proves the assertion, in this case also.$\qquad\square$

Comment: If $b=0$, $br+c=-ar^2$ does not imply a priori that $r\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If $$q^2=r_{\pm}^2+c^2=\frac{2b^2-4ac\mp 2b\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+4a^2c^2}{4a^2}$$ is rational, $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ must be rational as well, and so is $$r_{\pm}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ for whichever sign you pick.

Comment: @Ian Mateus Is it an answer to my comment ? If $b=0$, you cannot deduce from $q^2$ rational that $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is rational. Think of the case $a=1,b=0,c=-2$.

Comment: @IanMateus, Thank you, for your remark. I edited my answer, I think it is OK now.

Comment: @Omran Kouba: Verify your inequalities in the last line.

Comment: @Kelenner, Since $ca<0$ I think they are correct.

Comment: @Omran Kouba: But the power 2 seems not...Nice solution.

Comment: @Kelenner, Thank you, it is corrected. These are the typos of Copy and Paste!

Comment: It's Nice answer!@OmranKouba,Thank you

Comment: @Kelenner Indeed. Thank you.